# How to get my required date format?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

how to get this  format (jun-2016) from saledate (20160624)
only shown the first 3 character of month name, my saledate is nvarchar datatype in tblSale 
Thanks in advance

Comment: No I am new in sql server.

Comment: this is not a place for learn or ask for anything. Try to find tutorial and other help using google, or start learn SQL and other programming

Comment: Can you share some tutorial links that are helpful for begginers?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/SQL/wiki/index

Comment: This link is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple Try this one

```
    DECLARE @SaleDate NVARCHAR(20) = '20160624'

    SELECT  SUBSTRING(DATENAME(MONTH,@SaleDate),1,3) + '-' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4),YEAR(@SaleDate))
```

Comment: Thanks its helpful.